# Not able to capture previous API response and append the response in URL of Post Request API

Tags: json, karate

I am trying to POST API request where I am getting API response as

"d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "uri": "http://ev-qa02.zs.local/IncentiveManager/0002i1/wcf/v5.svc/InDataRequestCreators('9f31c6da-ec56-4360-8589-d21b6320f99b')",
      "type": "ZSAssociates.Javelin.ETL.Rest.v5.InDataRequestCreator"
    },
    "ScenarioId": "9f31c6da-ec56-4360-8589-d21b6320f99b",
    "CallbackUrl": "",
    "DataExpiresOnUtc": "/Date(4103913600000)/",
    "CreateScenarioIfMissing": false,
    "AdapterId": "0fcbd8d2-f5cb-4e2a-bda8-bb37037b022d",
    "InDataRequestIdOut": "eb36f8a9-5b7d-4835-88f6-4af67830c1e9",
    "InDataRequestUrlOut": "/InDataRequests('eb36f8a9-5b7d-4835-88f6-4af67830c1e9')"
  }
}

Now I am trying to hit another API request where my URL would be kind of 
http://ev-qa02.zs.local/IncentiveManager/0002i1/WCF/V5.svc/InDataRequests('eb36f8a9-5b7d-4835-88f6-4af67830c1e9')/FileCreator

*InDataRequests('eb36f8a9-5b7d-4835-88f6-4af67830c1e9') This random number is generated from above response value "InDataRequestIdOut"

How can I append the URL taking previous API response and adding in my 2nd POST request.
I am not able to capture my response and used it in other API POST request? i would realy appreciate if you can help me here,been stuck in this issue since couple of days,I went through doc and examples too but couldn't resolve this.I have attached screenshot too.[PostUrlFailureScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IckRw.png)
My main problem is line number 26 and 27 from eclipe screenshot

[image]

```
Scenario: Verify that JIM Idr request ofr Post
Given header Content-Type = 'Application/JSON'
And header Accept = 'Application/JSON'
And header Authorization = 'Basic 
UUEwMl9JbmNlbnRpdmVNYW5hZ2VyXzAwMDJpMTpZWkxaRjlGclR1eWhlcVNJbXlkTlBR'
Given path 'InDataRequestCreators'
* def user =
"""
{
 "ScenarioId":"9f31c6da-ec56-4360-8589-d21b6320f99b",
 "AdapterId":"0fcbd8d2-f5cb-4e2a-bda8-bb37037b022d",
 "DataExpiresOnUtc":"2100-01-18T00:00:00",
 "CreateScenarioIfMissing":"false"

 }
"""
And request user
When method post
Then status 201
* print 'the value of response is:', response
And def app = response
And path 'app.InDataRequestIdOut' + '/FileCreators'
* def body =
"""
{
 "InDataRequestId": "1d6326a2-d25f-41d2-9303-8a6e6101efcc",
 "ProcedureName": "",
"SourceWorkspacePath": ""
}
"""
And request body
When method post
Then status 201
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks to me you are using the wrong Eclipse plugin for Cucumber, please refer to this issue and make sure: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/90

There are so many things you are doing wrong. For example it should be `application/json` (lowercase). There are many places you are mixing upper case and lower case in your above description, please take care.

And there is no way to understand how the URL is being set up, without this - I can't provide proper help.

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use Karate expressions, for example this is just concatenating two strings:

`And path 'app.InDataRequestIdOut' + '/FileCreators'`

This may give you some hints, instead of the above:

```
When url baseUrl
And path "InDataRequests('" + response.InDataRequestIdOut + "')/FileCreator"
```

And is it FileCreator or FileCreators. You seem to be quite careless :(

Comment: please work with someone else who knows programming, you will solve your problem in 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks @Peter,I have resolved few of the things which you have mentioned,But I am still facing issue while capturing/saving response and using it in the URL.Its throwing me null.Currently getting POST [link](http://ev-qa02.zs.local/IncentiveManager/0002i1/WCF/V5.svc/InDataRequests('null')/FileCreator) I have replaced previous screenshot with new one above.                                                                                                
       And def app = response
       When url baseUrl
       And path "InDataRequests('" + app.InDataRequestIdOut + 
       "')/FileCreator"

Comment: @SaileshJoshi shouldn't it be `app.d.InDataRequestIdOut` look at your response JSON structure carefully. take the help of someone.

Comment: Thanks @Peter,It worked in the URL but didn't work in Request body,I guess I am declaring in a wrong way,Can you please guide me here.

 POST http://ev-qa02.zs.local/IncentiveManager/0002i1/WCF/V5.svc/InDataRequests('89cacddf-9fd9-4c08-93f7-516cfa514229')/FileCreator

* def body =
"""
{
  "InDataRequestId": "response.d.InDataRequestIdOut",
  "ProcedureName": "",
  "SourceWorkspacePath": "Ashwini/test2"
}
Instead of "InDataRequestId":"response.d.InDataRequestIdOut" = "InDataRequestId":"89cacddf-9fd9-4c08-93f7-516cfa514229" [Expected]

Comment: sorry can't help any more, all the best.

Comment: :-This is my last request :) please I am new to programming and just learning basics.This is last thing i would require for my project.* def body = """ { "InDataRequestId": "**response.d.InDataRequestIdOut**", "ProcedureName": "", "SourceWorkspacePath": "Ashwini/test2" }

Comment: Didn't get any help from developers too,Can u please help me :( ,As i mentioned It worked in the URL but didn't work in Request body,I guess I am declaring in a wrong way,Can you please guide me here. POST ev-qa02.zs.local/IncentiveManager/0002i1/WCF/V5.svc/… * def body = """ { "InDataRequestId": "response.d.InDataRequestIdOut", "ProcedureName": "", "SourceWorkspacePath": "Ashwini/test2" } Instead of "InDataRequestId":"response.d.InDataRequestIdOut" = "InDataRequestId":"89cacddf-9fd9-4c08-93f7-516cfa514229" [Expected]You can see in my above screenshot provided.How to declare in body

Comment: I got the solution used "InDataRequestId": '#(response.d.InDataRequestIdOut)' , ,Anyways Thanks @Peter